# Synology NAS: Sync multiple devices

Tags: networking, backup, nas

I'm trying to set up data synchronisation/backup for multiple Notebooks/Desktops (Win 10, Linux) to a Synology DS218+ NAS - but found no solution that provided what i want.

Basically, i want to:

- have a local folder on an arbitrary PC, containing data
- be able to work with the data offline (without the NAS available)
- have that same folder/data available on multiple devices
- the program used should monitor folder and file changes in the background, it should be an automatic sync without user action needed

Having exactly this setup for smaller files using Nextcloud (clients on every PC, cloud as central data storage syncing between all devices, real offline data on all devices), i now want to achieve something similar for bigger files, using my NAS.

Synology provided some Cloud Station or Cloud Sync applications, but this are deprecated and replaced by Synology Drive Server/Client. I don't want to use an already outdated tool, so i had a look at this Drive Server.

It does not work as expected, as it only provides access to the NAS Data on the PCs, so the NAS must be available in order to work with the data. I could find no way to change this behaviour to get a "real data copy".

I want to be able to work with the Data even without NAS or internet, so this isn't a solution.

Is there any good, approved way to use the DS218+ NAS in the way i want to?

---

**In case someone stumbles upon this:**

I got Synology Drive completely wrong. It does exactly what i want, the Application needs to be installed and configured on the NAS and there are clients vor Windows, Linux and Mac available.

It's using a folder on the NAS to store the Data. The clients create and sync local copies of this directory and it's contents, so it's available offline.

Works for me.

Comment: There are file synchronization clients that exist, have you ruled those out, to synchronize the folders in question?  Most of these clients support being ran as files are changed or every X minutes.

Comment: @Ramhound: Until now, i focused on what the DSM provided - can you name sync clients that could help me, that work with this NAS?

Comment: Any client that runs on the client’s OS should work (provided the client has the features you want).  Software recommendations are not allowed here at Super User.

Comment: Well, but... how's this working, without having the matching application on the NAS side installed? Every solution i've come across relies on such client-server applications - or is for just one explicit use case (like the Nextcloud client). Sorry, but i've never seen some kind of "install this client and it'll work with everything" solution.

Comment: You synchronize the changes with the software running on the client, the NAS would just be a file share, it does not need to support anything.  If it’s offline you cannot synchronize the files obviously because your file share is offline.  That would be the case no matter what solution anyone suggested other then perhaps making the files available offline but again changes to those files could not be synced.

Comment: "Cloud Station" needs server (NAS) and Client app installed, "Drive Server" too, "Resilio" too, "Syncthing" too - many others as well. I'd really like use what you describe and i totally understand it's not a technical thing, but that's how the software i found works and i haven't seen anything else* _(* Right now i'm trying a standalone client program called "FreeFileSync". No NAS installation, just a client tool, but ugly as hell, config like back in the 90s, no out of the box "runs in the background" function, it somehow sucks...)_

Comment: @Ramhound: Thanks for pointing me towards client-only programs! After testing some dozen tools, i've become friends with "FreeFileSync" now and it does exactly what i want.

Comment: @xph: You have a comment in your question, but you also have an answer you wrote yourself.  Which one is correct?  What steps did you actually take to make this work?

Comment: @briddums: For a while, i used the tool i found like described in the answer i wrote. That worked as intended, but i used that only because i missunderstood "Synology Drive", as mentioned in an update of my question. If you are using a Synology NAS, it would be best to install the "Synology Drive Server" there and the "Synology Drive Client" on your Notebooks etc. It works as intended, provides local offline data but syncs it to your NAS and across devices. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

*For future visitors:*

Thanks to **Ramhound**, who pointed me towards client-only programs.

When working with this DS218+ NAS, the first sync solutions you might come across are the ones provided by Synology, then other software found in the Synology package catalog - and many of them work as some kind of client-server-setup. You'd need to install a service on the NAS and client tools on the computers, set up connections between all machines and so on.

None of the tools i tested worked for me.

Either they don't provide two-way synchronisation, or they only provide a manual one-time-sync without folder monitoring, or the programs aren't available for linux, or...

**My solution:**

Search for *"free open source file sync program"*, get used to it's look and read the tutorials. It's a client-only program that just does the job right.

Comment: [Syncthing](https://syncthing.net/), `RoboCopy`, or `Rsync` - all can monitor for 1 change and sync when it detects the change.